# How to use Ansible Tower login credentials in playbook?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to use the credentials which I used to login into the Ansible Tower directly in a playbook?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can make it by saving your credential with the "**Ansible Tower**" credential type on your Ansible Tower.

> *From Ansible Tower UI, go to Credentials -> New Credential, and select the credential type as "Ansible Tower"*

This credential type takes three inputs, which are hostname, username, and password.
After you save the credential and add it to your job template as a credential, you can invoke them from your playbook like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Trigger an Atower API
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:

    tower_host: '{{ lookup("env", "TOWER_HOST") }}'
    tower_username: '{{ lookup("env", "TOWER_USERNAME") }}'
    tower_password: '{{ lookup("env", "TOWER_PASSWORD") }}'

  tasks:

  - name: Some tasks that can be achieved through "{{ apiEndpoint }}"
    uri:
      url: "{{ tower_host }}{{ apiEndpoint }}"
      method: GET
      url_username: "{{ tower_username }}"
      url_password: "{{ tower_password }}"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      validate_certs: False
    register: output
```

By the way, during looking for the right injection values for this case, I found the other values too for different credential types. Here you can obtain them:

```yaml
  vars:
    machine:
      username: '{{ ansible_user }}'
      password: '{{ ansible_password }}'
    network:
      username: '{{ lookup("env", "ANSIBLE_NET_USERNAME") }}'
      password: '{{ lookup("env", "ANSIBLE_NET_PASSWORD") }}'
    aws:
      access_key: '{{ lookup("env", "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID") }}'
      secret_key: '{{ lookup("env", "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY") }}'
      security_token: '{{ lookup("env", "AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN") }}'
    vmware:
      host: '{{ lookup("env", "VMWARE_HOST") }}'
      username: '{{ lookup("env", "VMWARE_USER") }}'
      password: '{{ lookup("env", "VMWARE_PASSWORD") }}'
    gce:
      email: '{{ lookup("env", "GCE_EMAIL") }}'
      project: '{{ lookup("env", "GCE_PROJECT") }}'
    azure:
      client_id: '{{ lookup("env", "AZURE_CLIENT_ID") }}'
      secret: '{{ lookup("env", "AZURE_SECRET") }}'
      tenant: '{{ lookup("env", "AZURE_TENANT") }}'
      subscription_id: '{{ lookup("env", "AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID") }}'
    rhev:
       ovirt_url: '{{ lookup("env", "OVIRT_URL") }}'
       ovirt_username: '{{ lookup("env", "OVIRT_USERNAME") }}'
       ovirt_password: '{{ lookup("env", "OVIRT_PASSWORD") }}'
```

Lastly, if you would like to do more flexible injections to your playbooks, you may check this link:

- [Ansible Tower Custom Credential Types](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credential_types.html)

Comment: Very helpful! Just a note, Ansible Tower version 3.3.0 switched the naming convention for the Ansible Tower credential type from TOWER_x to AWX_x (example: TOWER_HOST --> AWX_HOST). I had to switch mine to the AWX variables to get my playbook working. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/release-notes/relnotes.html#ansible-tower-version-3-3-0

Comment: @jake Do you know syntax for using the credential type "Github Personal Access Token"? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html#github-personal-access-token

Answer (score 0):

No, at least no in a conventional way that I'm aware of and without hacking the code.

When you create a credential in ansible tower for users to login, it is of kind "Ansible Tower". The credentials used in playbooks (jobs actually if we are talking about tower) should be of type "machine" or "github", which will give you the proper fields to fill things like keys, passwords, etc.

Comment: You can also request tokens using the /api/o/token endpoint by specifying null for the application type.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/2.2.0/html/userguide/job_templates.html

`tower_user_name`: The user name of the Tower user that started this job. This is not available for callback or scheduled jobs.